# Is it OK to call an action creator directly rather than through mapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I feel like the answer to this should be yes, but I just want to make sure.

I have these action creator imports:

```
import {
    updateField,
    goBackOneStep,
    finishStep
} from './signup_actions'
```

Then, at the bottom of this view, I previously had this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    updateField,
    goBackOneStep,
    finishStep
})(InputTel)
```

and I was calling `this.props.finishStep(INPUT_TEL, { tel }, null)`

But, then I modded the view to utilize Formik, which seems to prefer handling the submit action from its HOC, so now I have this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    updateField,
    goBackOneStep
})(withFormik({
    validate,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    validateOnchange: true,
    handleSubmit: ({ tel }) => finishStep(INPUT_TEL, { tel }, null)
})(InputTel))
```

I am just calling the action creator directly from the import. Is this OK in both React and React Native? (no anti-pattern or state confusion?). I can't find any docs to confirm, but I'm pretty sure I remember from a Stephen Grider React course that there is no difference calling it either way.

[edit]: Here is the final solution. I will include it due to its Formik-specific context:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    updateField,
    goBackOneStep,
    finishStep
})(withFormik({
    validate,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    validateOnChange: true,
    handleSubmit: ({ tel }, { props }) => props.finishStep(INPUT_TEL, { tel }, null)
})(InputTel))
```

Flying is correct, because Redux was not triggering a state change due to not calling the action creator correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your action creator directly, but in this case it will be called as a simple function, not as Redux action creator. As you can see from [`connect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) documentation - its `mapDispatchToProps` argument accepts function that allows wrapping your action creators with Redux's `dispatch()` that makes them actual action creators.

So to be able to use your action creator functions as action creators for Redux you need to either call wrap them into Redux's `dispatch()` by yourself by calling `dispatch(updateField())` instead of `updateField()` or use [`bindActionCreators`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) from Redux.